# Preimage of a simply closed curve under the two-dimensional antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, projective-space

> Suppose $p:S^2\to P^2$ is the quotient antipodal map, and $J$ is a simply closed curve in $P^2$, then $p^{-1}(J)$ is either a simply closed curve in $S^2$, or two disjoint simply closed curves in $S^2$.

I think I can prove the second case. Clearly $(S^2,p)$ is a 2-fold covering space. Suppose $J$ is totally contained in a basic neighbourhood $U$, of $P^2$, then $p$ is a homeomorphic projection on the two connected components of $p^{-1}(U)$, hence each component contains exactly one homeomorphic preimage of $J$.

Now I have trouble proving the other case where no basic neighbourhood can contain $J$. How to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's more productive to separate the cases in which the preimage is connected or disconnected. (The preimage can be disconnected even if $J$ is not contained in a basic neighborhood.) What results are available to you concerning the classification of compact curves?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang my course hadn't quite touched any classification theorem of compact curves. All I know is the non-self-intersecting definition of simply closed curves, and that a homeomorphic image of a simply closed curve is again so.

Comment: I see.... Do you have any results about coverings of circles, i.e., covering spaces whose base space is a circle? (Even if not, it doesn't look too difficult to cook up an argument from scratch. The important points are: The covering from the sphere to the projective plane is two-to-one and locally a homeomorphism, so sufficiently small intervals of $J$ come from _two_ intervals in the preimage; $J$ can be covered by "evenly-covered" intervals, and therefore by finitely many such intervals (since $J$ is compact). If $p^{-1}(J)$ is disconnected, $p$ maps each component homeomorphically to $J$.

Comment: Otherwise (modulo details), $p^{-1}(J)$ is a closed curve (it has the local structure of a curve, and is compact).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yeah I know that since the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\Bbb Z$ whose (normal) subgroups are $a\Bbb Z$, therefore by the classification theorem of covering spaces, all its possible covering spaces (up to isomorphisms) are either the exponential map $p:\Bbb R\ni t\mapsto \exp(it)$ which corresponds to $a=0$, or the Möbius map $S^1\ni z\mapsto z^a\in S^1$ which corresponds to $a\ne 0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I did try the localisation arguments. But the trouble is the preimage of each evenly covered interval of $J$ are two disjoint intervals in $S^2$, so when I tried putting $J$ back together it was hard for me to  grasp what happens to the preimage intervals.

Comment: If you can use knowledge of covering spaces, then $p:p^{-1}(J) \to J$ is a two-sheeted covering of the circle (i.e., of $J$) because $p$ itself is a two-sheeted covering. Either the total space is connected (hence a simple closed curve) or disconnected (hence has precisely two components, each mapped homeomorphically to $J$). :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see. So the gist here is that due to compactness $p^{-1}(J)$ is either a circle or two disconnected circles, since another possibility, $\Bbb R\to S^1$ is excluded because of its non-compactness? (Also I think you have implicitly admitted that any simply connected curve is homeomorphic to a circle.)

Comment: @Vim It's not about compactness. We know the parity of the cover; it's two-fold. Your favorite classification theorem of covering spaces says precisely what those two are. (You could indeed do it in this special case by invoking a classification of compact 1-manifold etc.)

Comment: @MikeMiller classification theorem doesn't seem to deal with the fold number (indeed I think it can be any-fold), but with each path connected component seen as an individual covering of the circle $J$. I think what's left to do is just to exclude the possibility of the exponential covering. (I thought it was compactness but yeah you are right compactness isn't useful here to determine the covering.). But now I don't know how to do it simply from the classification theorem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: See theorems 1.32 and 1.38 in Hatcher.

Comment: @MikeMiller sorry I made mistake. To rectify: if $p^{-1}(J)$ has two components then each component gets mapped homeomorphically to $J$, hence $p^{-1}(J)$ consists of two circles; if $p^{-1}(J)$ has only one component, then $p$ is literally a path-connected two-fold covering of the circle $J$, hence the covering should be the Möbius map of degree two, which makes $p^{-1}(J)$ a circle. Now I think I've got it straight! Thanks.

Comment: @Vim That's precisely it.

Comment: @MikeMiller there's another little question if you don't mind: about the first case, how do we conclude that on each connected component of $p^{-1}(J)$, $p$ is also a covering? Or, in general is there a theorem says that if $p:E\to B$ is a covering, $E$ consists of several connected components $E_\lambda$, then $p$ restricted to each $E_\lambda$ is again a covering? (Of course we can assume $B$ to be path connected and locally path connected etc.)

Comment: @Vim You're going in the wrong direction: the general theorem is that when you restrict to a subspace, the map $p^{-1}(A) \to A$ is also a covering map. This is usually given as an exercise; it's not too hard to prove.

Comment: @MikeMiller yeah. But now I think one needs the covering property on each component of $p^{-1}(J)$ separately to conclude each one is an identity möbius map (deg=1). Intuitively I'm guessing it's right, but have no clue for a proof.

Comment: This discussion is kind of suggestive towards the following: for a space $X$ there are $2$ different, $2$-sheeted coverings. This is not true. Generally (paracompact) there are exactly $H^1(X;\mathbb Z/2)$-many 2-sheeted coverings of $X$, and $H^1(X;\mathbb Z/2) = \mathbb Z/2)$. I know that it was not actively suggested, but observing how the OP raises questions, I am not sure if this was clear.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela sorry but what is $H^1$?

Comment: @DanielValenzuela I dont understand how you interpret it, but my main problem is: if $p^{-1}(J)$ has two components, say $A,B\subset S^1$, then how do we conclude that $p|_A,p|_B$ are both coverings in their own right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^2 \to P^2$ is a 2-sheeted covering map. Now note, that for any space $X\subset P^2$, the map restricts to a 2-sheeted covering map $p^{-1}X\to X$. If we pick $X=J$, then the covering map restricts to

$$ p^{-1}J \stackrel {2:1} \longrightarrow J\cong S^1.$$

So the preimage $p^{-1}J$ might either be homeomorphic to the unique covering space of $S^1$ corresponding to $2\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$, or be homeomorphic to the trivial covering space $S^1 \sqcup S^1$. Note that generally (not in this case for the Jordan curve theorem) the two curves might be knotted.

Comment: I'm curious to know how to conclude that apart from the second degree möbius covering map, the other one must be $S^1\coprod S^1$? I think this can be done via some localisation argument but is there a more elegant way? (See my last few comments to Mike Miller in which I talked about my puzzle, if you're interested)

Comment: What exactly do you know about covering spaces? (btw I just joined the discussion).

Comment: as far as classification theorem and something about deck transformation group. Just very elementary knowledge.

Comment: Okay good, so you should know that non-trivial covering spaces correspond to subgroups. Now note that there is only one possible subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ giving a 2-sheeted. Other case is the trivial covering, i.e. the disjoint union. Those are all 2-sheeted covers, by the covering space theorem which you know.

Comment: I need to know why the other case, the disjoint union, is the trivial covering on each component. I suspect a localisation argument would do the proof thanks to the compactness of $J$, which however would look quite clumsy and I'd like to avoid using here.

Comment: Look at my answer: it is a covering map. A trivial one, or, "corresponding to the zero subgroup". In particular you can lift $J \to p^{-1}J$, which gives you a homeomorphism to one component.

Comment: using lift sounds a good idea. However I don't think this covering corresponds to the trivial subgroup. Rather, it should be that each individual covering on a component corresponds to $\Bbb Z$, IOW, is the identity map, and there are two individual coverings, hence two sheeted in total.

Comment: the covering-subspace correspondence only applies when the covering is path connected. So the  first difference should be the connectivity, not the subgroup.

Comment: that's correct, and I emphasized it multiple times during my comments e.g. by putting it in exclamation marks, or by distinguishing that case. But it still makes sense. Maybe you should try to read the chapter about covering space theory in Hatcher, it will help you a lot!

Comment: so it does. I am reading Hatcher actually. The proofs are admittedly hard to read (harder than Rudin I would say), but the pictures are splendid.